# how to properly translate maven to gradle

Tags: java, android, maven, opencv, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to implement the example here
https://github.com/bytedeco/sample-projects/tree/master/opencv-stitching to my android project.

but I get all kinds of different errors...no luck at all.

I want to first make sure I'm referencing the correct lib. this example uses maven and its pom.xml can be found here. https://github.com/bytedeco/sample-projects/blob/master/opencv-stitching/pom.xml

this is a bit more complicated that what I can translate to gradle. I keep getting errors. Can someone please tell me what I should do to reference the same lib as the example? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this project is so small, you try doing `gradlew --init`. It will convert a `maven` project to a `gradle` project if it detects it.

Lets take the `pom.xml` files:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets.opencv</groupId>
  <artifactId>opencv-stitching</artifactId>
  <version>0.11</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
      <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.11-0.11</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is the same as a basic `build.gradle`:

```
group = "org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets.opencv"
version = "0.11"

dependencies {
  compile "org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:2.4.11-0.11"
}
```